# How to ues JsonConvert.DeserializeObject to convert array to Model in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

There is my data.

How to convert that to Model?

```
{"test": ["123","456"]}
```

Comment: [SO] is not a code writing service: what have you tried?

Comment: Sorry I make a stupid mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you already have a json string and want it to map it to a C# class construct you can use the intigrated Visual Studio function *Paste Json as Classes*.

1. Copy some JSON
2. Select Edit –> Paste Special –> Paste JSON As Classes

[image: Visual Studio screenshot]

If you do so Visual Studio will make for you this class:

```
public class Rootobject
{
   public string[] test { get; set; }
}
```

*Side note:*
*If you are not using Visual Studio you can go visit [this site](http://json2csharp.com/). Which will provide you the same feature with a similar result.*

To deserialize you simply call:

```
var json = "{\"test\": [\"123\",\"456\"]}";
var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
```