# Convert c# Object to JSON

Tags: c#, json, rest, serialization

I need to send a Json to a webservice. Im trying:

```
var user = new
{
    email = "user@domain.com",
    password = "user1234"
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
```

The result of this serialization is:

```
{"email":"user@domain.com","password":"user1234"}
```

But I need to pass the user inside the JSON:

Like this:

```
{ "user": { "email": "user@domain.com", "password": "user1234" } }
```

How can I do it?

Comment: `var toBeJsonified = new { user = user }`

Comment: Point to note: This looks like you are passing around plaintext passwords. That would be a very bad thing to do. Make sure you are hashing them, particularly before storing to disk.

Comment: If you know your desired output json format, but don't know how your class struct needs to look like to match your JSON. You can make use of a pretty handy Visual Studio function [Have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35061662/5453249). If you are not using Visual Studio you can make use of [this](http://json2csharp.com/) site.

Comment: Is this now solved?

Answer (score 9):

You need to wrap your object in an object with a `user` property then:

```
var user = new
{
    user = new
    {
        email = "user@domain.com",
        password = "user1234"
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

To achieve this you need to create the Classes as below:

```
public class User
{
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public User user { get; set; }
}
```

Create the object of the Root class:

```
User userInfo = new User();
userInfo.email = "user@domain.com";
userInfo.password = "user1234";

Root userdata = new Root();
userdata.user  = userInfo;
```

**Seralize the data as below:**

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userdata);
```

Comment: First, you don't **need** to create those classes. Second, what's the point if you don't use the `User` class (keeping the anonymous type for `userInfo`)?

Comment: Careful, in your edit you replaced `userInfo` with `userdata` but this becomes inconsistent (both your `User` and `Root` objects are called `userdata`, and `userInfo` - assigned to `userdata.user` - is never declared)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have edited the post. Yes, Class is not required but it is just other way to achieve it...

Comment: I like the idea of using classes, makes it cleaner. Still, you missed the parts `userdata.email` and `userdata.password`

Comment: It's my bad... edited again... You are really a good reviewer

Comment: Since OP is using an anonymous type, it's a bit overkill to suggest using a class. Also, I would use object initialisation syntax to simplify your code here - it's a lot more readable.

Comment: @DavidG, Agree with you

Comment: @DavidG that's right, plus that would have avoided my latest comment ^^ (and thank you Mittal, sometimes my brain acts like a compiler and when trying to process your code it broke - "*`Non-declared variable userdata`*")

Comment: It's not overkill to suggest using classes when there are easy to use tools that will generate them for you. [Visual Studio even has one built in](http://dailydotnettips.com/2017/11/09/did-you-know-you-can-automatically-create-classes-from-json-or-xml-in-visual-studio/).